# pathos multiprocessing objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess, pathos

I have a piece of code I am writing using pathos multiprocessing, which is producing an error. The problem is that distributing processes using pathos.multiprocessing.pool over a set of objects seems to do the work on a different object than that initialised in the class definition.

```
class Training_Set:

    def __init__( self, configurations ):
        print("Train init",configurations)
        self.configurations = configurations
        self.forces   = np.concatenate( [ c.reference_forces   for c in configurations ] )
        self.dipoles  = np.concatenate( [ c.reference_dipoles  for c in configurations ] )
        self.stresses = np.concatenate( [ c.reference_stresses for c in configurations ] )

    def run( self, config ):
        print("Train: run config",config)
        ran_okay = config.run( clean = True)
        if not ran_okay:
                return( False )
        return( True )

    def run_multi(self):
        pool_size = mp.cpu_count()
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=pool_size,maxtasksperchild=1,)
        print("Train run_multi: configs",self.configurations)
        pool_outputs = pool.map(self.run, self.configurations)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        if "False" in pool_outputs:
             return( False)
             self.ran_okay = False
        else:
             return( True)
             self.ran_okay = True

@property
def new_forces( self ):
            print("Train: New forces config",self.configurations)
            return np.concatenate( [ c.new_forces for c in self.configurations ] )
```

The configuration objects initialised in `__init__`, `run_multi()` and in `new_forces` are the same. So these configurations are those used in the call to `pool.map`:

```
 pool_outputs = pool.map(self.run, self.configurations)
```

But the objects being referred to in the `run` definition occupy a different part of memory.

Any ideas what might be causing this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the fact, that multiprocessing implies no shared memory?

Comment: I wasn't. Is there a way of forcing it to pass the object through rather than making another instance of it?

Comment: Not for Python classes. Python's `multiprocessing` (of which `pathos` is a fork) only supports shared memory for C-primitives.

Comment: Depending on what you do, you can rewrite this stuff. Can you describe your issue in detail? What is your input, what is the transformation and what is the desired output.

Comment: HI Eli, thanks for this. I have rewritten it. The code is embarrassingly parallel ( the script calls an mpi exectuable for a set of configurations at each step. I wanted to use multiprocessing to distribute the calls to the mpi executable over all the cores available, rather than run it serially on a given number of cores). There was no need to be passing the configuration object through, it just needed a bit of tinkering. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, this is the `pathos` author.  I'm a little late in the game, but @EliKorvigo is correct about the shared memory. `multiprocessing` (or `multiprocess`, the fork that `pathos` uses) does have shared memory objects (look at `Array` and `Proxy` objects). And if you are looking to work with MPI, I do have a somewhat less-supported package called `pyina` that provides a `map` interface for MPI and cluster schedulers.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the info. With pyina is it possible to have calls to the mpi-executable distributed across cpus on several nodes? I have pathos working on a single node, but ideally would like to be able to use more than one node. Thanks.